my query on subcollection in firestore does not return any data
I have a subcollection in a document on firestore, I can get all the documents in the subcollection if I do not put any condition in the query. This snipped works
 let q = query(collection(this.firestore,`providers/${providerKey}/locations`))
 onSnapshot(q, snapshot=>callback(snapshot))

if I put any condition:
let q = query(collection(this.firestore,`providers/${providerKey}/locations`))
q = query(q, where("status","!=","DELETED")
onSnapshot(q,snapshot=>callback(snapshot)
     onSnapshot(q, snapshot=>{callback(snapshot)}

I do not get any documents all the document in the subcollection has the field status, that is a string and in it  I have documents with status ACTIVE and DELETED, but nothing is found, for sure is my mistake, but I do not  understand what is wrong

thanks, I  have put onsnapshot inside the try catch, but I do  not get any exceptions, in other cases I saw that message and created the index how you said, but not in this case

If the problem only happens when you add a condition, it is most likely that you're missing the specific index that is required for this query.
The easiest way to validate this and create the index is to put a try/catch block around the code and log any errors you get. In that error you'll find a URL that takes you to the correct page of the Firestore console to generate the required index, with all necessary fields prepopulated. So all you'll need to do is open the link, click a button, and then wait until the index is created.
For more on this, also see the Firestore documentation on creating a missing index through an error message.
